# Looping slice value in HTML file

Tags: go

I have created slice of struct and an array of slice.

```
type blogs struct {
    id             int
    title          string
    featured_image string
    created_at     string
}
```

and created variable inside "xyz" function :

```
blog := blogs{}
blogData := []blogs{}
```

with value as :

```
    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT id, title, featured_image, created_at from blogs order by created_at desc limit 0,6")
    if err != nil {
        ctx.Application().Logger().Fatalf("MySQL Error fetching row %s\n", err)
    }        
    for rows.Next() {
        rcan := rows.Scan(&id, &title, &featured_image, &created_at)

        blog.id = id
        blog.title = title
        blog.featured_image = featured_image
        blog.created_at = created_at

        blogData = append(blogData, blog)
    }
```

and now, I have passed "blogData" value to "html" template and `iterating` below gives error :

```
  <ul>
  {{ range $value := .blogData }}
    <li>{{ $value.title }}</li>
  {{ end }}
  </ul>
```

Error :

```
template: master.html:18:5: executing "master.html" at <yield>: error calling yield: template: home.html:5:17: executing "home.html" at <$value.title>: title is an unexported field of struct type main.blogs
```

How can I print "title" and other value from `blogData` Variable in my template.

if I print `$value` , it returns all value in below format

```
{5 This is Title img/blog.jpg 2017-07-05T10:11:30+05:30 }
```

But I want to print, `title` , `featured_image` and other date separately.

Any help would be appreciated. I am using "github.com/get-ion/ion" framework

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access your struct field on template, it must be exported fields. Update your struct to-

```
type blogs struct {
    ID             int
    Title          string
    Featured_image string
    Created_at     string
}
```

Read more about [Exported/Unexported Identifiers In Go](https://www.goinggo.net/2014/03/exportedunexported-identifiers-in-go.html).

Comment: The only difference I see is capitalization ,is this what I need to use in my struct ?

Comment: Yes, capitalization of the first character is the salient detail, as explained in the link given.

Comment: Yes, Reading them. Thanks a lot :)